# co_await expression requires a suitable "await_ready" function and none was found

Tags: uwp, coroutine, c++-winrt

The following code for a C=/WinRT UWP app produces an error "this co_await expression requires a suitable "await_ready" function and none was found".

```
auto a = co_await Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(Windows::Media::Devices::MediaDevice::GetAudioCaptureSelector());
```

I am a novice at co-routines, and am not certain what is incorrect.
The Visual Studio project does have the /await command line option.

Comment: ``Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation`` is the Windows Runtime namespace used with C++/CX language extensions. Generally you use ``co_await`` with the C++/WinRT projection instead (``winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration`` namespace). See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/consume-apis).

Comment: Same error with the winrt:: prefix added                                                        
'auto a = co_await winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(winrt::Windows::Media::Devices::MediaDevice::GetAudioCaptureSelector());'

Comment: Is your project using C++/CX ``/ZW`` or C++/WinRT? If using the C++/WinRT projections, you must explicitly use the correct header, such as ``#include "winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h``. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency) for more information.

Comment: C++/WinRT; yes, #include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h> is in the pch.h header

Comment: What version of Visual C++ and Update level are you using? When I build this code using ``winrt::`` I get a different error.

Answer (score 2):

As of C++/WinRT 2.0, you need to include [winrt/coroutine.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/news#new-winrtcoroutineh-header) for all of C++/WinRT's coroutine support and winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h for collections. 
Also stick to C++/WinRT projection types (they start with winrt::) as @Chuck Walbourn mentioned.

Here's my snippet:

```
// pch.h
...
#include <winrt/coroutine.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Media.Devices.h>
...

// MainPage.h
...
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs const&);
...

// MainPage.cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::OnNavigatedTo(Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation::NavigationEventArgs const& e)
{
    auto collection{ co_await winrt::Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(winrt::Windows::Media::Devices::MediaDevice::GetAudioCaptureSelector()) };

    for (auto const& deviceInformation : collection)
    {
        OutputDebugString((deviceInformation.Name() + L"\n").c_str());
    }
}
```

Comment: Still worth pointing out, that the diagnostic in the question is not a compiler error. It's what IntelliSense spits out when you hover over the squiggles. The actual compiler error is different, and way more intimidating.

Comment: Build: 1 succeeded

Comment: The information is no longer correct, see [coroutine support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/news#coroutine-support): *"**Coroutine support is included automatically**. Previously, the support resided in multiple places, which we felt was too limiting. And then temporarily for v2.0, a `winrt/coroutine.h` header file was necessary, but that's no longer needed."*

Comment: @IInspectable it looks like he can now simply replace `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction` return type with `fire_and_forget`, and remove the `#include <winrt/coroutine.h>` correct?

Answer (score 0):

This IntelliSense diagnostic is generated, when you place a `co_await` expression in a function that isn't itself a coroutine:

```cpp
void foo() {
    auto a = co_await DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(MediaDevice::GetAudioCaptureSelector());
}
```

The issue isn't with the `co_await` expression itself; it is the result of the `void` return type. To fix this you'll have to provide a suitable return value for the function that is meant to be a used as a coroutine, e.g.:

```cpp
IAsyncAction foo() {
    auto a = co_await DeviceInformation::FindAllAsync(MediaDevice::GetAudioCaptureSelector());
}
```